# codeigniter url parameter interchange

Tags: codeigniter

my current url is http://localhost/ci/test_test/test/12/abc

12 is my id and abc is the value which are to be passed in the function test

now i want that my url would look like this http://localhost/ci/test_test/test/id/12/val/abc
function may know that after the id keyword its the id and after the value keyword its the value

```html
public function test($id="",$code=""){ 
        $data['id']=$id;
        $data['code']=$code;
  $this->load->view('welcome_message',$data);
 }
```

Comment: why do you want to add **id** and **val** in url? Any specific reason?

Answer (score 5):

In your routes.php , set your url like this :

```
$route['test_test/test/id/(:num)/val/(:any)'] = "path/to/your_controller/$1/$2";
```

and your controller :

```
public function your_controller($id="",$val){
    //...
}
```